# Massive Memory usage of Node process while importing a million documents using MongoDB Node Driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using
MongoDB : 3.0.6
Node Driver for Mongo

I have to import a Million documents into Mongo. I create arrays of 1000 documents and call insertMany() to insert them in bulk. The process finishes in ~70 seconds

While this is happening, I see the Node Process Memory Usage spike from ~100MB to around ~800MB.

Is that Memory Leak . If yes, how do I go about identifying the Memory Leak ?
If not, what is  the explanation for this behavior ?

Edit: Below is the Code I use.

```
var csv = require('csv'),
fs = require('fs'),
Q = require('q'),
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var COLLECTION_NAME = 'transactions';

var insertDocument = function(db, doc) {
return db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).insertMany(doc);
};

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:" + 27017 + "/integration",      function(err, db) {
if (!err){

    console.time("Import Time");

    var csvParser = csv.parse({
        columns: true,
        trim: true
    });

    csvParser.payload = [];

    var promisesArray = [],
        batchReadCount = 0;

    csvParser.on('readable', function() {

        var data = csvParser.read();

        if (data !== null) {
            csvParser.payload.push(data);
            batchReadCount++;
        }

        if (batchReadCount == 1000) {
            promisesArray.push(insertDocument(db, csvParser.payload));
            batchReadCount = 0;
            csvParser.payload = [];
        }
    });

    csvParser.on('end', function() {
        if (csvParser.payload.length > 0) {
            promisesArray.push(insertDocument(db, csvParser.payload));
        }

        Q.all(promisesArray).then(function(result) {
            console.timeEnd("Import Time");
            docdb.close();
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            console.timeEnd("Import Time");
        });
    });

    var readStream = fs.createReadStream('million.csv');

    readStream.pipe(csvParser);
}
```

})

Comment: Hard to tell without any actual code to look at

Comment: Yes you should post your code so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Node memory management is lazy, by default it will do a gc when it reach ~ 1.3/1.4 Gb of memory. The goal is to do less gc as possible as it's an I/O blocking operation.

So it can be normal.

You can try to set the flag : `--max_old_space_size=500`
ie `node --max_old_space_size=500 app.js`
That should tell node to do a GC around 500/600mb of memory use. If you are around that number you don't have memory leak, only lazy GC. If it's start crashing, you may have leak.

Comment: Thanks for that info. With the above flag, I observe that whole Import Process slows down once Node reaches ~500MB.

Comment: But the Node process does not crash.